# Generating multiple plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, docx

I am trying to generate 2 `matplot.lib` graphs in `docx` file. The first graph I generate works perfectly. However, the second plot that i generate is superimposed onto the first graph (i can't figure out why)

My first graph reads a csv file and to generate the plots values, while my second graph just uses hard cded values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

        #making a plot from a csv file that was uploaded to DB table
    if FileUpload.objects.filter(attribution_file_upload='pftest4.csv').exists():
        life3 = pd.read_csv(FileUpload.objects.get(attribution_file_upload='pftest4.csv').attribution_file_upload)
        life3.plot(kind='bar', x='status', y='item')
        plt.title('my plot title')
        plt.xlabel('years')
        plt.ylabel('Age')
        memfile = io.BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(memfile)
        doc.add_picture(memfile, width=Inches(4))
        memfile.close()

    #making a plot out of numbers that are already stored in saf defect table DB table
    y1 = 3
    y2 = 5
    korea_scores = (y1, y2)
    col_count = 2
    bar_width = .2
    index = np.arange(col_count)
    plt.bar(index, korea_scores, bar_width, alpha=.4, label="Korea")
    memfile2 = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(memfile2)
    doc.add_picture(memfile2, width=Inches(4))
    memfile2.close()
```

in the picture attached you will see what is happing to my second graph. my second graph should only have 2 value. but instead these 2 values are generated along with all my first plot values. any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can start a new plot with a fig, ax = plt.subplots() and you can use the ax keyword argument in df.plot(..., ax=ax) and use matplotlib's object oriented API. See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html

Comment: You could call `plt.clf()` after your first plot has been saved. The figure gets erased automatically when you call `plt.show()` but not with `plt.savefig()`. For example when you are constantly adding information to the same figure and want to save all the steps, you don't want the figure to be erased in-between.

Comment: @JohanC that is perfect it worked. i just added `plt.clf()` and now my 2 plots are individual. thanks really appreciate it. I've been trying to figure it out for ages.